# How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery in a page from other page dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I made a dashboard for my e-commerce website from where there is an option to selected page
after selecting a particular page if i press save button there i want to run these codes on selected page dynamically by which i can use scriptAnalytics.js file only for the pages i want.

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src","scriptAnalytics.js")
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Comment: Are your pages in iFrame or what? Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: My page is an usercontrol named Dashboard.aspx in which i'm trying to do like this.... PageURL: /Checkout.aspx , on Dashboard.aspx control i have a button so i want to run above script on the click of the button dynamically on Checkout.aspx page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery Ajax function to load and run your script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    success: successFunction()
 });
```

or try to use shorthand method [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 2):

You can load js dynamically using jQuery.getScript() method on the page you want.